# RestAssured ResponseBodyExtractionOptions: How to filter json objects from json

Tags: java, json, http-get, rest-assured

I have a endpoint which responds with

```
{
  "fruits" : {
    "apple" : "green",
    "banana" : 99,
    "oranges" : "floridaBreed",
    "lemons" : "sicilian",
    "grapes" : "red",
    "cherries" : 12,
    "guava" : "sour",
    "tomato" : 13,
    "melons" : "yellow",
    "pomegranate" : 37,
  },
  "isRaw" : null,
  "foodtype" : {
    "typeOne" : "non-veg",
    "typeTwo" : "veg"
  },
  "isCooked" : [ ],
  "isReady" : [ ],
  "isExpired" : [ ],
  "isHealthy" : null,
  "serialnumber" : 5555,
  "isAvailable" : "Yes",
  "dietValue" : {
      "nutrition" : [ {
          "vitamin" : "yes",
          "vitaminValue" : 3
      }, {
          "calcium" : "no",
          "calciumValue" : 0
      } ]
  },
  "isEdible" : null
}
```

I have some code that gets this, bit I'm unable to get the nested value objects. For example I can get value for 'isAvailable' which is ='yes' But if i want to get value for 'grapes' or for 'calcium', then it does not work. Any ideas?

```
public String sendGetMessageValue(String messageId) {
    Map<String, String> response = doInternalModuleApiGet(messageId, 200);

    return response.get("fruits.grapes");
}

public Map<String, String> doInternalModuleApiGet(
        String messageId,
        int expectedStatus) {
    String url = getInternalUrl() + "/" + messageId;
    return sendHttpGetRequestAndGetResponse(url, expectedStatus).as(Map.class);
}


private ResponseBodyExtractionOptions sendHttpGetRequestAndGetResponse(String url, int expectedStatus) {
return given()
        .header("Authorization", "basic " + B64Code.encode("dummyuser:dummypass"))
        .get(url)
        .then()
        .log().ifError().and()
        .assertThat().statusCode(equalTo(expectedStatus)).and().extract().body();
}

public String getInternalUrl() {
    return ("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api");
}
```

Comment: Why you are not ising jackson to deserialize the JSON

Comment: I'm not aware, could do. Can you please give an example

Comment: or use @Rohan Kadu solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library is easy to use. Example code below:

```
JSONObject completeJSON= new JSONObject(" ..YOUR JSON String Goes Here.. ");
String grapes= completeJSON.getJSONObject("fruits").getString("grapes");//Level2
String available= completeJSON.getString("isAvailable"); //Level1
```

---

You can get this details by modifying code as below :

```
public String sendGetMessageValue(String messageId) {
    Map<String, String> response = doInternalModuleApiGet(messageId, 200);
     String fruits = response.get("fruits.grapes");
 JSONObject fruitsJSON= new JSONObject(fruits );
fruitsJSON.getString("grapes");
    return response.get("fruits.grapes");
}
```

You may find extra examples from: [Parse JSON in Java](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/)

[Downloadable](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

Comment: How would you fit it in my current code? Looks very helpful, thank you

Comment: Yes, I have done like you said, it looks good. One final compile error. It is returned as map

    return sendHttpGetRequestAndGetResponse(url, expectedStatus).as(Map.class);

But we use String
String fruits = response.get("fruits.grapes");

Comment: Error is: JSONObject() in JSONObject cannot be applied to (java.lang.String).

Comment: You have converted above JSON into a Map and accessing data from that Map with key. Map will work perfectly for one level of data in any json parent object. But point where you require second level data you will need to parse one more level down and use that JSON data for further details.